# How to implement subscription to the CalDav server

Tags: calendar, scheduling, icalendar, caldav, webcal

Should I implement CalDav client to synch with external CalDav server ? Or CalDav server can do it somehow ?

Like in apple calendar, I have to input server url, username, password
If I want to add this functionality to my service, how it should be implemented ?

Researched all over the internet, but found no answers